# What is the meaning of “Expression de besoin”?

Tags: sens, travail

What are the contexts of saying “*Expression de besoin*” in a “*Document de travail*”?

I read this in a document explaining a certain work but I didn't understand what extent is the person trying to explain the work.

Comment: The full quote would help.

Comment: added the full quote

Comment: Oh well, that's not a lot clearer, but that definitely helps. Doesn't sound very native to me, though, especially in the singular form. I'd say you'd better off asking the author what he really meant…

Comment: my dear friend if the author as helpful, stackexchange would not have been needed ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a software development context, this document is part of the requirements and is the starting point before writing code.

The main client (the owner of the application) generally writes an “*Expression de Besoin*”
then the “*Maîtrise d'ouvrage*” will translate the needs into functional specifications and finally the IT contractor (“*Maîtrise d'œuvre*”) will write some technical specifications then code what is needed to answer the needs.

In real life the IT contractor generally goes straight to code without writing technical specifications.

Comment: +1 cuz ur such a nice kitteh. (Well, excellent explanation, also. Welcome to FL&U by the way :)

Comment: Generally found as "expression des besoins" and means "customer requirements". Requirements are inputs used by a supplier or a contractor to design a solution and a proposal for the customer. This is not limited to software engineering. To obtain a valid proposal, a customer has first to express its needs. "Document de travail" means "draft document" or "work in progress".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "Expression de besoin - document de travail" is the title of a document, it would be better to use "expression de besoins" or "expression des besoins" which are literal translations of "statement of requirements" and is a step (or the product of a step) in some IT project management methods.

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of is “*l'expression d'un besoin*”, that is, someone is in need of something (*besoin*), and expresses it. The result, what he said or wrote, then is “*l'expression d'un besoin*”.

That said, I think we lack some context, it could wel lbe something else I didn't think of.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be pretty close to the [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Requirements_Specification), which is a standard document from IEEE that defines the framework of the software development through discussion between the customer and the contractor. Since the customer is king, in French, he is expressing his needs in this "expression de besoin" document that the contractor will have to fullfill.

Answer (score 1):

J'utilise le document "l'expression de besoin" pour transmettre mes commandes vers le fournisseur. C'est un document officiel qu'on signe avec le fournisseur.